# Can't set alias in zsh --- command not found?

Tags: command-line, zsh

I'm trying to set `alias conky-lua ="conky -c ./.conky/conkyrc &"` so to start conky-lua. but when I source `.zshrc` it says command not found.

A possible solution that I found on Stackoverflow is to set `alias ls='ls -GpF'`didn't solve the problem

Comment: Avoid spaces around the = symbol...

Comment: @Rmano ok thank you, I think that was the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the space around the `=` in the command. 
Look:

```
[:~] % alias a=ls
```

this works as expected

```
[:~] % type a
a is an alias for ls
```

But

```
[:~] % alias b =ls    
[:~] 1 %
```

This does not work. `zsh` see two words, `b` and `=ls`; it uses the pathname expansion on the second one, and execute `alias b /bin/ls` --- it exits silently with  error code 1 because neither `b` or `/bin/ls` are alias (`alias` without `=` checks if a name is an alias).

```
[:~] 1 % alias c ="ls -l"
zsh: ls -l not found
[:~] 1 %
```

This fails in a more strange way; the shell is trying to expand the full path of the command "ls -l" (*with* the embedded space in the command name) and so it is failing in looking for it.